# Contra/Covariance With Generics - Can't Assign to T

Tags: c#, generics, covariance, contravariance

Code:

```
public interface IAssignable
{
    IAssignable AssignMe { get; set; }
}

public class GenericAssignExample<T> where T : IAssignable
{
    private T _assignable;

    public void Valid(T toAssign)
    {
        _assignable.AssignMe = toAssign;
    }

    public void AlsoValid(T toAssign)
    {
        _assignable.AssignMe = toAssign.AssignMe;
    }

    public void AlsoValidAsWell(T toAssign)
    {
        _assignable = toAssign;
    }

    public void Invalid(T toAssign)
    {
        _assignable = toAssign.AssignMe;
    }
}
```

Problem:

In final example method `_assignable` (which is `T where T is IAssignable`) cannot be assigned the value `toAssign.AssignMe` (which is of type `IAssignable`), the compiler throws

> "Cannot implicitly convert type 'IAssignable' to 'T'".

Why is this? `T` is `IAssignable` so surely an instance of `IAssignable` can be assigned to it?

Comment: `T` is `IAssignable` but `IAssignable` is not `T` which is required if you're assigning to `T`.

Comment: Purely for the record, if the inferface itself is generic and the class constraint restriction enforces that type to return a type of itself, the syntax would be valid `public interface IAssignable<T>
{
    T AssignMe { get; set; }
}

public class GenericAssignExample<T> where T : IAssignable<T>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why is this? T is IAssignable so surely an instance of IAssignable can be assigned to it?

Ah, no? `T` is *not* `IAssignable`, if it were, you would not need Generics. `T` just *implements* `IAssignable`.

Just because `Button` and `TextBox` inherit from `Control` (or in a fictional example implement `IControl`) does not mean you can assign a `TextBox` to a `Button` or vice versa.

---

```
public interface IAssignable
{
    IAssignable AssignMe { get; set; }
}

public class A : IAssignable
{
    public IAssignable AssignMe { get; set; }
}

public class B : IAssignable
{
    public IAssignable AssignMe { get; set; }
}

// You will be able to instantiate this class with either A or B and both must be valid
public class GenericAssignExample<T> where T : IAssignable
{
    // here, T refers to either A or B.
    private T _assignable;

    public void Valid(T toAssign)
    {
        // assigning either an A or B to the interface... 
        // always valid, both implement it
        _assignable.AssignMe = toAssign;
    }

    public void AlsoValid(T toAssign)
    {
        // assigns interface to interface. Always valid.
        _assignable.AssignMe = toAssign.AssignMe;
    }

    public void AlsoValidAsWell(T toAssign)
    {
        // assigns either an A to an A
        // or a B to a B.
        // both always valid.
        _assignable = toAssign;
    }

    public void Invalid(T toAssign)
    {
        // this tries to assign an interface to either an A or a B
        // always invalid.
        _assignable = toAssign.AssignMe;
    }
}
```

Comment: But I'm not assigning an implementation, I'm assigning a reference to the interface right? T in this context is always the interface?

Sorry if this is a dumb question. But surely following your logic the other 2 methods shouldn't compile either (as I'm assigning T to an interface there as well)?

Comment: No, T is not always the interface. If that were the case, why use a T, why not just write `IAssignable`? `T` in your case is constraint to *any class implementing* `IAssignable`.

Comment: When you assign something to `T`, you *do* assign something to the implementation.

Comment: Ok so could explain why the other examples compile? I've just added an extra example that also compiles.

Comment: Thanks nvoigt, clears it up :-) is this anything to do with Contravariance or Covariance or do I need to go an do more homework?

Comment: No, co- and contravariance did not yet come into play. It's a normal instance of "you cannot assign two types, just because they implement the same interface".

Answer (score 0):

Just cast it to IAssingable:

```
_assignable.AssignMe = (IAssignable)toAssign;
```

Comment: That line never had errors from the start. The cast is unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

I thinks I know where it is that you are confused, note here the difference

```
public interface IAssignable
{
    IAssignable AssignMe { get; set; }
}

public class GenericAssignExample
{
    private IAssignable _assignable;

    public void Valid(IAssignable toAssign)
    {
        _assignable.AssignMe = toAssign;
    }

    public void AlsoValid(IAssignable toAssign)
    {
        _assignable.AssignMe = toAssign.AssignMe;
    }

    public void AlsoValidAsWell(IAssignable toAssign)
    {
        _assignable = toAssign;
    }

    public void Invalid(IAssignable toAssign)
    {
        _assignable = toAssign.AssignMe;
    }
}
```

now it should work as you intended. Notice however that here you are always working with the interface type, when you make a generic interface/class with constraints all you're doing is narrowing the types that can be used along your class.

In your `Invalid` method what is happening is that you are using an `IAssignable` object and assigning it to a `T` object, and even though `T is IAssignable` there is no warranty that `toAssign.AssignMe` is the same type, hence your error. In the modifications I made above you loose generics and then the actual type you're using is `IAssignable` so it all works fine.

Hope that helps

Comment: Yea that does solve the problem, once again I think I've tried to shoe horn generics into my solution when there was no need to do so. (The code sample isn't from my actual solution it's just the bare bones of the code to illustrate my problem)